# Appended node does not trigger JavaScript event

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have an inventory with some slots in it. With some actions from the client, new items are added to these slots by the `appendChild` function.

```html
<div id="letters">

  <div class="slot">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="slot"></div>
  
  <div class="slot">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

With the following code I try to trigger a `mouseover` event for each slot.

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");

items.forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    //Stuff
  });  
});
```

It works perfectly fine, but when I add a new item to a class `slot`, this one does not trigger the event.

Can anybody guess the problem?

Thanks a lot!

**Edit:**
I solved the problem by adding a new eventListener too whenever I append a new item. `EventListener`s must be added before using them (pretty obvious), and in my code I was working with them as if they were `onmouseover` functions.

Comment: The item does not exist when you added the *immediate events* so .. it doesn't have the event(s) added. Use *deferred / bubbled events* (ie. see what jQuery does) or add the event *to each [newly created] item*.

Comment: I also think, you should add the event to the newly created element explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the handler to the newly constructed element after it is created.

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");

function attachMouseOverHandler(element) {
    element.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOverHappened);
}
items.forEach(attachMouseOverHandler);

function addNewElement(element) {
    attachMouseOverHandler(element);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the append, you need to add the event listener to the new element, as it did not exist when you originally created the event listeners.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using a single deferred event listener, so you don't have to dynamically add new event listeners:

```js
document.getElementById('letters').addEventListener('mouseover', function (event) {
  const element = event.target;

  if (!element.matches('.item')) return;

  //Stuff
  console.log(element.textContent.trim());
})
```

```html
<div id="letters">

  <div class="slot">
    <div class="item">
      Foo
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="slot">I do not match .item</div>
  
  <div class="slot">
    <div class="item">
      Bar
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```